# get specific value from object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need to get an value from an object given below, Here i need to get "value" from below object,

```
var a = { 'getData': [ { title: 'posted By', value: '18th Sep' } 
 ] };

here i am trying like a.'getData'[0].value;
```

here i need to print the value '18th sep'

Comment: The single quotes have no place being there. (They are not part of the key, but of the object notation syntax. And in this case, a superfluous part at that.) `a.getData[0].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a.'getData'[0].value` is not valid JavaScript syntax.

You can simply access the required value using standard [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#dot_notation), e.g.

```
a.getData[0].value.
```

Or you could use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation) if you wished, e.g.

```
a['getData'][0]['value']
```

```js
var a = { 'getData': [ { title: 'posted By', value: '18th Sep' } ] };
console.log('Value (dot notation):', a.getData[0].value);   
console.log('Value (bracket notation):',a['getData'][0]['value']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways:

1. `a['getData'][0].value`
2. `a.getData[0].value`

Both should work.

See the [property accessors documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for details/examples.